# mysql query safe limit

Tags: php, mysql, json, angularjs

I'm quite inexperienced in this area so it may seem like a dumb question, but please bear with me.

Got a `mysql` DB and a query, via `PHP PDO` that look like this:

```
SELECT p.*, group_concat( distinct c.color) as color, b.breeder_puppy_thumb , b.breeder_name
FROM puppy_list p 
JOIN puppies_join_colors pjc ON p.ID = pjc.puppy_ID 
JOIN puppy_colors c ON c.ID = pjc.color_ID 
JOIN breeder_list b ON b.ID = p.puppy_breeder_id 
WHERE p.puppy_breed = :breedName
GROUP BY p.ID
ORDER BY p.price DESC
```

The `ORDER BY` clause can vary (can be ordered by a different field).

I send this query via `AJAX` to a `PHP` file that sends it to the DB server - so round trip, **4 hops**.

In my website, there is pagination and it's done on the fly, all data is in memory in the form a big JSON object - and the processing is done on this JSON object, in the front end framework (`angularJS` based - pagination too), without querying the DB again.

My first question is: given a query like this one, with the rows returned being in the thousands (tens of thousands) what's a safe limit to put in place on a single query? How many rows should i return so that i won't overkill the client?

My second question is: should i move part of the processing away from angular to the back-end framework or go with it like this?

If i didn't formulate the question well enough, please let me know and i'll try and address that.

Comment: How do sites you like do it? Default pagination 50 but tweakable by user? Have as much as possible server-side. Many pagination samples here

Comment: @DrewPierce Hard to say. The only website that compares (from what i know) is airbnb.com - and it appears they do queries to the DB on each page request - i'm trying to avoid to do one on each request, but perhaps one in steps of 40 (looking for the biggest safe number). So page 1, page 40, page 80 .. would get the next chunk of data.

Comment: Look at url params like here on s.o. (i am sure you have)

Comment: Server: LIMIT {[offset,] row_count ...

Comment: @DrewPierce Not exactly aplicable. The website i'm working on, needs to behave (to feel) like a one page app - stackoverflow has a partial like behavior. Meaning, when i optimize my website, i'm trying to push for as little back and forth requests as possible, hence why i'm thinking what's the limit of the data returned i can get away with - something along those lines.

Comment: @DrewPierce I know how to do it, i'm thinking of a number. Is it safe to return 1000 rows? How about 10000? This is where my lack of experience comes in (prefaced the question with that).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82404/discussion-between-radu-andrei-and-drew-pierce).

Comment: How miserable do you want them to be? Test it :)

Comment: Right now i am on a cell network. You shove me large pagination i retreat

Answer (score 0):

@Radu Andrei, Drew Pierce has some valid points.

On your first question => you can do what Facebook is currently using, "Infinity Scroll". It is a fancy way of displaying pagination. Loads more results when the user reaches the bottom or displays a "load more" button.
See an example here: http://www.w3bees.com/2013/09/jquery-infinite-scroll-with-php-mysql.html

On your second question => a good programming solution is to have both back-end and front end working properly in case a user disables java-script. However, nowadays js is enabled by default. I would say keep the JS front end and have the back-end programmed as well. You never know what users disable. Always keep mobile devices in mind while doing this, they may not appreciate 1000 items per page especially nowadays, almost all our browsing is on mobile devices.

Comment: First point - design restriction prevents infinite scrolling. Second point - if a user disables JS, the site breaks because it's build on AngularJS.